# code convert binary to decimal

Tags: python, binary, decimal

I wrote this code to convert binary to decimal it's not the best code because I am a beginner. here is the code:

```
def bin_dec(a):
   binary_list = list(str(a))
   binary_list.reverse()
   g = 1
   double_list = [1]
   for i in binary_list:
       g = g * 2
       double_list.append(g)
   double_list.pop()
   l = 0
   ans = []
   while l < len(binary_list):
       g = binary_list[l]
       if g == "1":
           k = double_list[l]
           ans.append(k)
       l = l + 1
   return "Decimal Value : %r" % sum(ans)
```

you get a "0" if you do this print bin_dec(01101) output = "0" but if you do this print bin_dec(1101) the output is "13"

the code works pretty well but the problem is when the binary number starts with a zero like "00110" or "01010" Python immediately changes it to an octal number, causing the code to fail it ends up outputting "0" I have tried to change the variable "a" with the oct() function but it also changes binary numbers that don't start with 0. they only way that seems to work was using `raw_input` like
`a = raw_input("type Binary Number : ")` but I don't want to do that. I am hoping someone can help me. I also don't want to use any python functions to convert the binary number to decimal. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by " when the binary number starts with 0"? How are you passing the inputs?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 : OP explicitly said he didn't want to use a built in

Comment: I cant reproduce your error, this works for me. It can definitely be more elegant though, and see the answers below for some tips on that

Comment: you get a "0" if you do this print bin_dec(01101) output = "0" but if you do this print bin_dec(1101) the output is "13"

Comment: @jacoblaw you get a "0" if you do this print bin_dec(01101) output = "0" but if you do this print bin_dec(1101) the output is "13"

Comment: @ubaobasi `bin_dec('00110')`` prints `6`, bin_dec('001101')` prints `13` for me. Python 3.6.0 windows 7

Comment: wait you run it by passing an int or a string?

Comment: @jacoblaw "00110" is an int not a string so it looks like print bin_dec(00110)

Comment: you're using python 2.7?

Comment: @jacoblaw yes python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
def bin_dec(a):
    result = 0
    for bit in a:
        result *= 2
        if bit == '1':
            result +=1
    return result
```

No functions at all, not even `append`, `pop` nor `reverse`! ;->
Oh, but you still have to use `raw_input` - unless you switch to Python3,  where `input` will do.

Comment: Do you actually need the `if` statement? As `bit` is always `0` or `1`, can't you just say `result+=bit`?

Comment: I assumed `a` is a string, thus `bit` is `'0'` or `'1'`, so: no. But `result += bit == '1'` would work.

Comment: @Błotosmętek then you can still do `result+=int(bit)`

Comment: "a" is not a string it is an int. i run the code like this print dec_bin(01101) 01101 is written as an int

Comment: @Błotosmętek "a" is not a string it is an int. i run the code like this print dec_bin(01101) 01101 is written as an int

Comment: Ah. Then you've got a problem.

Comment: @Błotosmętek the code works if i use a string but i want it to use integers any suggestions?

Comment: Well, sorry, you cannot. Integers with leading zeros are interpreted as octal numbers by Python2 (but not by Python3!)

Answer (score 3):

I like short pythonic solutions, so here you go

```
def bin_dec(a):
     return sum([int(a[-i])*2**(i-1) for i in range(1, len(a)+1)])
```

or, even shorter:

```
bin_dec <- lambda a: sum([int(a[-i])*2**(i-1) for i in range(1, len(a)+1)]))
```

Comment: That's my personal favourite. Lambda methods make the code much cleaner and simpler.
But can I ask you one thing, why do many people don't like lambda methods?

Comment: @anugrah They are less readable, and generally super long lines in python are bad form.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.